# Existe alguma maneira de alterar uma mensagem de um commit?

Tags: git

Eu trabalho com `git` em todos os projetos da empresa onde trabalho. Infelizmente, alguns programadores acabam por colocar  uma mensagem qualquer, em um momento de pressa, num `commit`. Isso dificulta as coisas, pois ao invés de você ver a descrição do que foi feito no `git log`, você passa a ter que "chutar" pela data de um `commit` específico.

Alguns colocam coisas como `git commit -am ":)"` ou `git commit -am "tudo"`.

Exemplo:

```
commit 18d76fbaa661945ef59f675092f5050d3d7016a3
Merge: 7f0aea2 8ca43f6
Author: XXX XXXX <xxx@email>
Date:   Wed Feb 17 10:26:40 2016 -0200

    all

commit 7f0aea214c26e84b18a8768a7d282b760b7a230a
Author: XXX XXXX <xxx@email>
Date:   Wed Feb 17 10:22:38 2016 -0200

    all
```

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de reverter tais lambanças.

Existe alguma forma de editar uma mensagem de um commit específico?

Comment: O que posso fazer para melhorar minha pergunta? O voto negativo é nesse sentido?

Comment: Tem um jeito mais fácil, faça um upgrade de programadores ou troque eles por versões mais novas onde esse bug já foi corrigido :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do [Rodrigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113881/41113), se você quiser apenas alterar a mensagem do último commit, utilize `git commit --amend -m "SUA NOVA MENSAGEM AQUI"`.

Mas se você quiser alterar qualquer outro commit, inclusive o primeiro commit do repositório, utilize `git rebase -i --root`

Em seu editor de texto padrão do terminal (nano, vim, etc) vai abrir um arquivo começando com algo similar a isso:

```
pick 4c5877b first commit
pick edbd6ae second commit
```

`4c5877b` e `edbd6ae` são os dois commits existentes no meu repositório de testes, e `first commit` e `second commit` são as mensagens de commit que eu usei.

Troque `pick` por `r` ou `reword` em todos os commits que você deseja alterar e salve o arquivo. No meu caso eu quis modificar o `second commit`, então ficou assim:

```
pick 4c5877b first commit
reword edbd6ae second commit
```

Vai aparecer no seu editor de texto as informações do(s) commit(s) que você quis alterar, incluindo a mensagem do(s) mesmo(s). Altere-a(s) e salve o(s) arquivo(s).

Meu git log antes do rebase:

```
commit edbd6ae914877887c8304895d3a2a1fc4d95769a
Author: xyz <xyz@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 22 20:23:22 2016 -0300

    second commit

commit 4c5877b870d177d5a9dd432ff87a7b006efbc29c
Author: xyz <xyz@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 22 20:23:22 2016 -0300

    first commit
```

e depois:

```
commit e462bfac89165e5af4e0aec60e6758330cbe196d
Author: xyz <xyz@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 22 20:23:22 2016 -0300

    MODIFICADO second commit

commit c3a909e630a806b01d099bf40319cdbc26c96a59
Author: xyz <xyz@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 22 20:23:22 2016 -0300

    first commit
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, valeu :)

Answer (score 3):

É possível alterar a mensagem mais recente com o comando:
git commit --amend

Para alterar mensagens mais antigas, é necessário alterar a base de onde você está trabalhando para que a mais recente seja a de cima.